# skybox error c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm creating a skybox with opengl everything compiles but when the program runs nothings changed but after looking through the build report I got this error

> warning LNK4031: no subsystem specified; CONSOLE assumed

Any idea what this means? I'll supply any code if needed.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem.

Set it to `Windows` or `Console` as you prefer - `Console` will build as a Console application, it'll have a preallocated console when it starts. `Windows` will build as a non-console application, and require a `WinMain` instead of a `main`

Answer (score 2):

It means the /SUBSYSTEM switch wasn't supplied to link.exe.

Here is the documentation on that switch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx

If you're building a console application, you'll want to use /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE.  If you're building a Windows application, you'll want to use /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can modify the "SubSystem" setting under "Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System".